# Rotated pole CRS can't be inserted into GeoTIFF

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I have data on a rotated pole projection that I want to serve with GeoServer. I am currently trying to use GeoTIFFs to do so. GeoTIFFs were generated from the original data with `xarray` and `rasterio` (through `rioxarray`).

**Problem**

The problem is GeoServer fails when I try to import the GeoTIFFs. But if I copy the CRS string in a `*.prj` file, then GeoServer is able to read the files. For logistic reasons, because I have 10k layers, I would have liked to skip this "prj" file necessity. Also, I'd like to understand what's going on.

**Data and logs**

The crs string as it appears in the `.prj` file and in the `epsg.properties` of GeoServer:

```
PROJCS["rdrs_rotated",GEOGCS["unknown", DATUM["unknown", SPHEROID["unknown", 6371220.0, 0.0]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH]], PROJECTION["Rotated_Pole"], PARAMETER["central_meridian", -92.4030], PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 58.2417], PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], UNIT["m", 1.0], AXIS["Easting", EAST], AXIS["Northing", NORTH], AUTHORITY["EPSG","971807"]]
```

This is the string I explicitly pass to `rioxarray` which then get written into the GeoTIFFs. `gdalinfo` gives another version of the CRS when I check it:

```
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["rdrs_rotated",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_unknown",
        DATUM["D_unknown",
            ELLIPSOID["unknown",6371220,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Rotated_Pole"],
        PARAMETER["central_meridian",-92.403,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",58.2417,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        PARAMETER["scale_factor",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1,
                ID["EPSG",9201]]],
        PARAMETER["false_easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["m",1]],
        PARAMETER["false_northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["m",1]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["m",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["m",1]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (5.687788100469680,-12.735000534217898)
Pixel Size = (0.089999970935640,0.090000000320563)
```

And when I import only the GeoTIFF file, `Geoserver` fails with :

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:///data/geotiffs/espog_tg_mean_annual_ssp245_p50_1951-1980.tiff and hints Hints: EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7a8fcfa2[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@3f487e86 System defaults: LOCAL_DATE_TIME_HANDLING = true GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@5af1884e FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true
```

in the GUI and with many errors in the logs. I summarize here:

```
28 Aug 15:20:33 WARN   [gce.geotiff] - GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only Geographic & Projected Systems are supported.  
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only Geographic & Projected Systems are supported.  
...
Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only Geographic & Projected Systems are supported. 
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only Geographic & Projected Systems are supported. 
...
28 Aug 15:20:33 INFO   [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:///data/geotiffs/espog_tg_mean_annual_ssp245_p50_1951-1980.tiff
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:///data/geotiffs/espog_tg_mean_annual_ssp245_p50_1951-1980.tiff and hints Hints:
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create reader from file:///data/geotiffs/espog_tg_mean_annual_ssp245_p50_1951-1980.tiff
```

**What else I have tried**

I have tried setting the CRS in the geotiff directly with `gdal`:

```
gdal_edit.py -a_srs "$(cat rotated_pole.prj)" rotated_layer.tiff
```

And the result is exactly the same. `gdalinfo` shows the exact same CRS and Geoserver fails the same way.

QGIS is also unable to open the GeoTIFFs, it says "unknown crs".

**Questions**

Is there a way to avoid giving a "prj" file for each of my 10k GeoTIFFs ?

I populate the GeoServer instance through REST API calls, if that helps. If there was away to provide the "proj" string through the layer creation call, that would be good enough for me.

Comment: see https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools,/projections,/itches/2017/10/20/adding-prj.html for a quick way to add `.prj` files to lots of tiffs - but it would be interesting to see what is going on internally. Turn logging up to GeoTools dev and then open a ticket with the geotiff, and the log file and a link back to here